# Where do bash script save the stdout and stderr when the log file is manually deleted during runtime?

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr

```
#!/bin/bash
python /home/sites/myapp/Main.py &> /home/sites/myapp/logs/init.log &
```

This script produces a log of approximately 1G/week.
When i manually delete the init.log during runtime and not restarted the script it still save the data in a missing init.log. init.log will be visible again when the script is restarted.

Does restarting the script the only way to see the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On unix system When `init.log` is created then an [inode](/questions/tagged/inode) is created. There is a counter in every `inode`s which counts all the references to that file. A reference means a hard link or when a file is opened. The file is only deleted when this counter goes back to zero.

So when stdout is redirected to `init.log` its `inode` has the counter value 2 (referenced by the directory entry, and counted because of `open`. When `rm` (uses `unlink` function) deletes the file, this counter become 1, so file is not referenced by any directory entry, but the `inode` still exists. When the script finishes, the counter become 0 and the `inode` is deleted.

There is no easy way to read an inode, which not referenced by any directory entry.

Comment: Thank you TrueY. This makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

A file is not actually deleted until nothing references it.  In this case, you have deleted all directory entries, but your program still has an open file descriptor so the data is not completely removed until the program exits.  Note that it will also continue to hog disk space.

In Linux, you can still view the file's contents in `/proc/PID/fd/FD` where PID is the process's id and FD is the file descriptor that your are interested in.  Once the program exits, the data is toast and the disk space can be reclaimed... so get your data while you can ;)

You shouldn't remove a log file if you know that a program still has open file descriptors on it.  Instead, truncate the file with `cat /dev/null > log.file` or in bash just use `> log.file`.

Comment: It consumes disk space in `home/` partition not the `/` where `/proc/PID/fd/FD/` can be found